# Decent way to toggle the text of bootstrap popover?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the angular + bootstrap to create a table and for each row, it will have a popover button. What I want to do is to change 'Show Password' to 'Hide Password' when the popover is shown, and change back when the popover is closed.

```
                    <tr ng-repeat="entry in data">
                        <td>{{ entry.site }}</td>
                        <td>{{ entry.username }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button popover-placement="right" uib-popover="{{calculatePassword(entry)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Show Password</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

I tried to use lines such as 'displayed? "Show Password":"Hide Password"' but I can't find a proper spot to toggle 'displayed'. I can't find a built-in feature of uib-popover to do that neither. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-click` to toggle a variable each time the button is clicked and change the text accordingly.

```
<button ng-click="entry.passwordDisplayed = !entry.passwordDisplayed">
  {{entry.passwordDisplayed ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Password
</button>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

app.controller("controller", function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.data = [
    {
      site: "Facebook",
      username: "jsmith",
      password: "abc123"
    }
  ];
  
  var trusted = {};
  
  $scope.htmlPopover = function(entry) {
    var html = '<b>Password:</b> ' + entry.password;
    return trusted[html] || (trusted[html] = $sce.trustAsHtml(html));
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Site</th>
          <th>Password</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="entry in data">
          <td>{{ entry.site }}</td>
          <td>{{ entry.username }}</td>
          <td>
            <button ng-click="entry.passwordDisplayed = !entry.passwordDisplayed" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-popover-html="htmlPopover(entry)" class="btn btn-default">{{entry.passwordDisplayed ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Password</button>    
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, but I think ng-click is not working with uib-popover....

Comment: @Hanks it's working with uib-popover in the code snippet